# Laravel relationship structure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table of fixtures which looks like this;

- user_id
- opponent_id
- gameweek
- league_id

I also have a results table that stores the result of the fixture as and when they come in.

- user_id
- gameweek
- league_id
- result

What i am struggling is with the relationship between the two and how to call that relationship when i need it.

Essentially, each fixture contains two results; one user_id_result and one opponent_id_result (both of which refer to an id in the users table)

I did something like this in the Fixture model;

```
public function userResult()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Result', 'league_id', 'league_id')
        ->where('user_id', $this->user_id)
        ->where('gameweek', $this->gameweek);
}
```

And, although this worked, I don't think it's quite right and also did not work when called through eager loading.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a good database structure which is probably where the root of your problem lies.  Both tables have 3 columns which are the same thing.  Not only is that inefficient but also confusing.

At first glance, it would make more sense to drop 3 columns in your results table, `user_id`, `gameweek` and `league_id` and replace them with a `fixture_id` which is what will handle your relation.  `fixtures.id = results.fixture_id`.

I don't know what's being stored in this, but it's possible to simplify it even further by dropping the `results` table all together and just adding the `results` column onto the `fixtures` table.  Let it be null and when the game is done, update that column.

Comment: Thanks - I see your point. I was under the impression that having null items in a database was generally a bad idea? It would not only be one null result, but 2 (user and opponent result). It made more sense to me when i was planning the database to have the results stored separately.

Comment: I don't think having null columns are particularly bad as long as you know what they mean.  If you will be storing 2 results, then there should be a better way.  Can you give an example of what a result would be?  I'll think about it and edit my question with a better solution.

Comment: A result will simply consist of one value; the result. Plus a user_id and any other pairings required (fixture_id?). The fixtures user_id and opponent_id are both using the user table